# how to use filter in angularjs with id relevant name based filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my `angular` app, I have to work in filter functionality but I am not able to get my output. I have stored the `id` in DB, but at `ng-repeat` I'm using function and get relevant id based name from another scope. it's working fine but the filter is not working.

NOTE: iFilter is working based ID, I need to filter based `name`, please help how to do this

template code:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="json1.Name" class="searchbox" />
<hr/>Ng-Repeat<hr/>
<div ng-repeat="json in myJson | filter:json1">
  <li>  {{showCartName(json) || 'select'}}</li>     
</div>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$filter){
  $scope.myJson = [{id:1},{id:2}]
  $scope.myJson1 = [{id:1,Name:"one"},{id:2,Name:"two"}]

  $scope.showCartName = function (json) {
    var SelectStream = [];
    if (json.id) {

      SelectStream = $filter('filter')($scope.myJson1, { id: json.id });
    }
    return SelectStream.length ? SelectStream[0].Name : 'Select';
  };
})
```

here i attached my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/629/)**

Comment: To share links, use following structure `[Link text](Link url)`

Comment: @Pengyy how to solve this problem

Comment: next time when you ask a question, please consider make it more readable. :-)

Comment: You want the list to be filtered based on name?

Comment: yes filter based on name my data structure is be like in fiddle

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/631/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44470064/6230347) is sufficient.

Although you can also use [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters), this gives you flexibility in implementing any logic you desire.

add this in your controller :

```
$scope.customFilter = function (json){
        if ($scope.json1 === undefined) return true;
        else{
         var Name =  $scope.showCartName(json);
            return (Name.indexOf($scope.json1) !== -1);
        }
    };
```

and change in HTML :

```
 <div ng-repeat="json in myJson  | filter:customFilter">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/638/

Comment: hi @shivam it's working correctly but based on Uppercase may be data in Caps means i should enter caps then only work help how to solve that one

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/640/ you can create a temporary string with lower or upper casing and convert your input to the same casing and make a check like  Name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.json1.toLowerCase()) !== -1  OR  Name.toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.json1.toUpperCase()) !== -1

Comment: Thanks once check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568522/enter-value-auto-caps-in-editable-text-using-angularjs @Shivam Tiwari

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough for your requirement.

```
 <div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
 <input type="text"  ng-model="json1.Name" class="searchbox" />
 <hr/>Ng-Repeat<hr/>`enter code here`
 <div ng-repeat="json in myJson1 | filter:json1.Name">
    <li>    {{showCartName(json) || 'select'}}</li>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/636/

Comment: my data is look like this in my fiddle i need that type of filter :)@thanveer pu