# Enter value auto caps in editable-text using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

hi all i am using `angularjs` editable-text i am trying to do when i enter the in editable-text that value should be changed to uppercase while i typing but i am not able to get my need anyone can help

here i attached my fiddle
:http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/NfPcH/19035/

Answer (score 0):

add this in your controller

```
 $scope.convertToUpperCase = function(user){
        user.name = user.name.toUpperCase();
  }
```

and call it on `onshow`

```
  <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onshow="convertToUpperCase(user)">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
```

see this http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/19577/

Comment: while typing it's lowercase  i need upper case while typing

Comment: you can also add a watch on "user.Name" like this  $scope.$watch( function(){ return $scope.user.name
        },function(){ $scope.user.name = $scope.user.name.toUpperCase();});
but that will also trigger only after focus moves out of the text box

Comment: if you can't find any other way to achieve this, you can get rid of "editable-text" directive and write your own custom directive and do anything inside that.